# Gradle spring boot - /health endpoint not responding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot rest api project - I can't get the spring boot actuator /health endpoint to work.  It's simply not showing up and I get a 'Whitelabel Error Page' when I try to go to localhost:8080/health.  I've tried adding various properties to my application.properties but none seem to work - I don't need any custom mappings or authentication to the actuator endpoints anyways.  Below is my build.gradle - any advice?  I think I'm missing something.

Thanks.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url = 'https://artifactory.company.com/libs-release' }
        maven { url = 'https://artifactory.company.com/libs-remote' }
        maven { url = 'https://artifactory.company.com/libs-snapshot' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE")

    }
}

plugins {
    //id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.5'
    //id 'ch.netzwerg.release' version '1.2.5'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'


bootJar {
    baseName = 'equipment-workorder-api'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

// Inject test phases into the main build task
build.dependsOn('test')

jar {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource + sourceSets.test.allSource + sourceSets.test.output
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    maven {
        name "libs-release"
        url "https://artifactory.company.com/libs-release"
    }
    maven {
        name "libs-snapshot"
        url "https://artifactory.company.com/libs-snapshot"
    }
    maven {
        name "libs-remote"
        url "https://artifactory.company.com/libs-remote"
    }
    maven {
        name "spring-milestones"
        url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone"
    }
    maven {
        name "jitpack.io" // this is for spring-test-junit5, remove once we upgrade to spring 5
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    //Spring Boot
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-actuator", version: "1.5.8.RELEASE"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-configuration-processor", version: "1.5.8.RELEASE"


    //Logging
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'


    //JUnit / Mockito
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version:'5.0.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version:'5.0.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.2")

    //Swagger
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'


}


}
```

Comment: Did you try changing  the version of Actuator? On one hand you have: `[...] spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE` while in the dependencies: `[...] "spring-boot-actuator", version: "1.5.8.RELEASE"`.

Comment: I tried this     dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE")

    }

Comment: and get the same result

Comment: I would recommend adding `debug = true` to your application properties to you should see a autoconfiguration report. You should see `HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration` being enabled, or a reason why if it was not conditionally enabled

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get the health status via HTTP, you may want to add this dependency and have a try:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.8.RELEASE'
```

Comment: that is not required in boot < 2.0, its pulled as a transitive dependency

Comment: hi @DarrenForsythe i have created a sample springboot app using springboot 2.0.4.RELEASE but i did't see any spring-boot-starter-web transitive dependency,

Comment: As I said, in less than 2.0 its not required. From Boot 2.0 onwards you need to define the dependency as there is the option of `web` or `webflux`.

Comment: I havealso  test with springboot 1.5.14.RELEASE  there is no web transitive dependency, means you can't access http

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose endpoints from application.yml file to be able to see actuator/health endpoints result.
In Gradle we use application.yml file for this so just write the below configuration in this file:

```
management:
 endpoints:
  web:
   exposure:
    include: "*" #<2>
 endpoint:
  health:
   show-details: ALWAYS
```

You can anytime exclude any endpoints you wish to.